# the method replace is not applicable for arguments

Tags: android

I am getting a compile time error `The method replace(int, Fragment, String) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, VideoListFragment, String)` at VideoActivity.java.Below I am posted the codes related to that.

**VideoActivity.java:**

```
package com.sit.loco.activity;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import com.loco.android.R;
import com.sit.loco.frgment.VideoListFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class VideoActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener, VideoListFragment.OnVideoSelectedListener{

    // create object of ActionBar and VideoListFragment
    ActionBar actionBar;
    VideoListFragment videoListFrag;

    int selectedItem;
    private String TAG;

public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        selectedItem = itemPosition;

        // create object of VideoListFragment and send data position to that fragment
        videoListFrag = new VideoListFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("position", itemPosition);
        videoListFrag.setArguments(bundle);

        // call video list fragment with new data
   getFragmentManager()
   .beginTransaction()
   .replace(R.id.content_frame, videoListFrag, "VIDEO_LIST_FRAGMENT")--->Error at Compile time
        .commit();
        return true;
    }
}
```

**VideoListFragment.java:**

```
package com.sit.loco.frgment;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class VideoListFragment extends Fragment {

OnVideoSelectedListener mCallback;

boolean loadingMore = false;
}
```

**MyFragmentPagerAdapter.java:**

```
package com.sit.loco.provider;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    final int PAGE_COUNT = 6;

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    /** This method will be invoked when a page is requested to create */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        switch (arg0) {
        case 4:

            VideoListFragment videoList = new VideoListFragment();
            data.putInt("position", arg0);
            videoList.setArguments(data);
            return videoList;
}
}
}
```

I didn't know how to solve this.Anybody can help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: Does VideoListFragment inherit from Fragment?  https://github.com/WhiteHouse/wh-app-android/blob/master/src/gov/whitehouse/ui/fragments/app/VideoListFragment.java suggests it does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant use FragmentManager with Fragment that uses Support Package (`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`)
replace the `getFragmentManager()` to `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: thank you.it worked for me.will accept your ans in two minutes something shows wrong here.

Comment: Yes Sorry LOL its ok.. :)